# Setup Mobfox in Admob

Tags: admob, mobfox

I'm trying to setup MobFox in Admob , ask me the API Key, I take the apikey that is on My Account / Account Information , but always gets the status of pending before the Admob and most times the apikey field is reset.

How do I proceed to setup the right way?

Comment: I am having the same issue, were you able to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean "Ad network optimization settings", yes you should use that.

If you mean AdMediation I believe you should use as **Inventory Hash** (former publisher id) which you will find at your integrity section of your ad on Mobfox. However I tried all options and still have pending in AdMob mediation report.